# SVG loader not spinning correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to update an svg loader from a smil animation to a css animation.

This is the original svg and the CSS animations:

```css
svg path
{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin
{
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@keyframes spin
{
  0% { transform:rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="130px" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 80 80;" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 25 25" to="360 25 25" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
</svg>
```

It looks correct in Chrome but all wrong in Firefox and I can't understand why (try the [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrPdpZ) to see what I mean).  Any ideas why?

Comment: `-moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite` . Why `animation-duration` is set to `3s` in this, but `0.6s` in others.

Comment: It would be better to use `font awesome` icon.

Comment: @iNullPointer ah I was testing it, slowing it down to see what was happening in Firefox.  Font awesome has gone a bit rubbish recently with tiered versions.  I use it a lot but looking to move away now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for me in Chrome either. At least not with recent Chromes anyway - which have a correct implementation of `transform-origin`.

```css
#loader-2 path
{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin
{
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@keyframes spin
{
    0% { transform:rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="130px" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 80 80;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 25 25" to="360 25 25" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="loader-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="130px" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 80 80;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z"/>
</svg>
```

The problem is that, in SVGs, the percentage `transform-origin` coordinates are calculated relative to the whole SVG. Not the element they are used on.

So `transform-origin: 100% 100%;` here means the bottom right of the SVG. Not the bottom right of `<path>`.

The fix is to tell the browser that you want the origin to be calculated ralative to the path.  You do that with the following property:

```
transform-box: fill-box;
```

Demo:

```css
#loader-2 path
{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 0.6s linear infinite;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin
{
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}

@keyframes spin
{
    0% { transform:rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
    100% { transform:rotate(360deg); transform-origin: 100% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="130px" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 80 80;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 25 25" to="360 25 25" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" id="loader-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="130px" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="enable-background:new 0 0 80 80;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Right understood.  Unfortunately doesn't fix the issue for me as transform-box  was only implemented in Firefox 55.  Looks like I will be throwing away the svg @Kosh Very.  Marking this answer as correct.

Comment: If you need to support older browsers, then the fix is use absolute (ie `px`) coordinates rather than percentages.  Use `transform-origin: 25.25px 25.14px;`. This will work in all browsers that support `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 1):

Trow away your svg =))

```css
.loader
{
    width:50px; height:50px;
    border:solid 7px transparent;
    border-top-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
    border-radius:55%;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin
{
    100% {transform:rotateZ(360deg)}
}
```

```html
<hr class="loader">
```

Comment: Yes I realise I can do this, just as I could have used a png but I'd actually like to know what's happening differently in Firefox.

Comment: IMHO, it's always better to do simple things simple than do them complex and wonder what's happening in Firefox (IE, Safari etc.)